# Missing CGridView Alias in Yii

Tags: yii, cgridview

When i trying use

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Votes');
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.СGridView', array(
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
));
```

I got an error:

> Alias "zii.widgets.grid.СGridView" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.

Why Yii did't see the CGridView class? I even tried to do the import command in Yii config. All files is exists.
What i must do for minimal actions for this one (CGridView table)

Comment: why did you not specify the data provider?

Answer (score 0):

You have cyrillic 'C' symbol in `CGridView` class name

Comment: Thank you)) I don't know how u found it oO